# addTagHelper Html.GetEnumSelectList Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Just getting back into coding after a long hiatus... I'm trying to display a list from an enum using Html.GetEnumSelectList<>, however Visual Studio 2019 does not seem to recognize (no intellisense) and the code is not working.

```
@using AspNetCoreVideo.Models
@model AspNetCoreVideo.Entities.Video
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers

<h2>Create Vidio</h2>
<form asp-action="Create" method="post">

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label asp-for="Title"></label></td>
        <td><input asp-for="Title" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label asp-for="Genre"></label></td>
    <    td><select asp-for="Genre" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Genres>()"></select></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Create" />

</form>
```

Expecting a list of "Genres" to display, however, nothing is in the list.

Answer (score 7):

I also had the similar issue, the select was showing nothing. Later I found that it was because of the usage of the select tag. If you use it as a single element like this `<select />` it isn't gonna work. You have to use it as `<select></select>`
Hope this would help someone.

Comment: THIS.  Holy cow that's a stupid glitch... but yeah... this.  This was the answer.  [/facepalm]

Answer (score 1):

Issue Resolved. Apparently, @addTagHelper directive is case sensitive. I changed "@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers" to "@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers" and now the tag helpers work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting intellisense is because you didn't prefix it with an `@`, so it's just plain text. You only don't need the `@` on `asp-for`. That's because it's accepting a model expression, whereas something like `asp-items` needs an actual instance of some collection. In other words:

```
<select asp-for="Genre" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Genres>()"></select>
```

Comment: I'm following an example straight from a book. The author's working code also does not use the '@'. I tried prefixing with @, but that shows an error "Cannot convert method group 'GetEnumSelectList' to non-delegate type 'object'.

Comment: That's an exception you'd get if you weren't dereferencing the function, which based on the code you posted, you are (i.e. adding the `()` at the end). Make sure you actually are. Other than that, not sure what to tell you. You definitely need the `@`: that would seem to be a publishing error in the book. The helper still definitely exists, so no problems there.

Comment: I resolved the issue. Apparently, @addTagHelper directive is case sensitive. I changed "@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers" to
 "@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers" and now the tag helpers work fine.

Comment: Sorry. I actually noticed that but thought it was a typing error, when you were constructing the question. Yes, *everything* is case sensitive. You're referencing a namespace there. When in doubt, assume casing was purposeful.